# How do I make 2 teams of equal size and skill level given an array of 20 players with varying skills - and make it scalable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting

This was asked to be solved in PHP, but the concepts from any language would do.

This was asked to be scalable i.e. you can add players after, and your algo would still work.

You're given 20 total players (more can be added). Each is individually ranked with a skill level of 1-10.

You're asked to provide 2 teams with an equal amount of people, and as close to equal skill level as possible.

Comment: Do you want the sum of the skill levels to be the same?  Do you want people's skills to be matched as closely as you can?

Comment: Each team's skills have to be as closely matched as possible - and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list of players by their skill level. Calculate the median value of the skill levels, such that as many players have skill levels above the median as players with skill levels below the median.

Find the next nearest player's skill level. The first two selected players, one on each team are the player with the median skill level, and the next nearest skill level.

Find the next two players whose score is closest to the first two players scores. Swap those players and place them on the teams. Then take the next two and don't swap them. The next two, swap them. And so on.

The algorithm should work whether you've got 8 players or 108 players. And with a few changes, it should support 2 teams with 20 players, or 100 teams with 20,000 players.

Let's create an example. 8 players, named A through H with skill levels 0 through 9. So player B7 is named B with a skill level 7.
Your available players are:

- A4
- B9
- C7
- D3
- E5
- F5
- G1
- H8

Sorting by skill level gives us:

- G1
- D3
- A4
- E5
- F5
- C7
- H8
- B9

The median skill level is 5. The next nearest skill level is also 5, so the first two players selected are E5 to TeamOne and F5 to TeamTwo.

The next two players would be A4 and C7. Swap them. C7 goes to TeamOne and A4 goes to TeamTwo.

The next two players would be D3 and H8. You swapped the last two, so don't swap these two. D3 goes to TeamOne and H8 goes to TeamTwo.

The next two players would be G1 and B9. You didn't swap the last two, so swap these. G1 goes to TeamTwo and B9 goes to TeamOne.

Now you have 2 teams, each with 4 players, whose skill levels are approximately the same.

The resultant teams would be:

```
TeamOne:
 - E5
 - C7
 - D3
 - B9
Average skill level is 6.

TeamTwo:
 - F5
 - A4
 - H8
 - G1
Average skill level is 5 (to the nearest whole skill level).
```

The more players you have to work with, the more closely team skill levels will be matched.

The PHP code to implement this should be fairly simple to write.